# Need a way to share credentials for different clientele

Tags: passwords, account-security

I am an independent technology consultant, and I am running into a worrying and recurring issue with my customers regarding sharing account information. Many solution we use I am able to be added as an account to work on their systems, but some are limited either by billing or by an inability to allow outside email domains. In these cases, my customers are oftentimes sending me their username and password unprompted via email.

I am trying to find a password manager or other such solution that will allow me to send requests for user information that can be stored securely and then ideally deleted after time or prompting from myself or the client. I have looked into several of the larger password managers such as LastPass, NordPass, and Keeper but have not found any solution that works for disconnected organizations. Keeper and LastPass have a sharing function, but it only seems to work with licensed users in a shared org.

Anyone have any insights into software or methods of collecting this use data securely with accountability features?

Comment: I think the technology you are looking for is PAM. Look at things like CyberArk and Delinea. And depending on the thing you are logging into, CASB might be an option, too.